# CMMotionActivityManager does not work on iphone 5 ios 10.3.3

Tags: ios, core-location

Can't google anything for an error `CoreLocation: CMErrorDomain Error occurred while trying to retrieve motion state update: Code: 104`

In addition to this, this block of code does not work on iphone 5 ios 10.3.3:

```
private let motionManager = CMMotionActivityManager ()

motionManager.startActivityUpdates (to: .main, withHandler: {[weak self] activity in self? .setActiveMode (activity? .stationary ?? false)})
```

Something tells me that this is due to an error in the top.

P.S. on iPhone 8 ios 12.0 everything works.
P.S. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iPhone 5 does not support `CMMotionActivityManager`

iPhone 5S is the first Apple's device with M7 coprocessor.
You must check [isActivityAvailable()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmmotionactivitymanager/1616116-isactivityavailable) before to start ActivityUpdates

```
if CMMotionActivityManager.isActivityAvailable() {
          ///startTrackingActivityType()   
}
```

Comment: @СынБожий Depends what you want. If you only need accelrometer, gyroscope or device-motion data, - you can use `CMMotionManager` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmmotionmanager